# How to solve the error "ValueError: Expecting , delimiter"?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I cannot find out why the following lines of code do not work:

```
text = '''{"seasons":"[{"season-type":"type1","start-day":10,"start-month":1,"end-day":31,"end-month":5},{"season-type":"type2","start-day":1,"start-month":9,"end-day":9,"end-month":1},{"season-type":"type3","start-day":1,"start-month":6,"end-day":30,"end-month":9}]"}'''
obj = json.loads(text)

obj
```

I get the following error `ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 16 (char 15)`

Comment: You seem to have quoted the list which is the value that the key `"seasons"` refers to.

Comment: It has to be `text = '''{"seasons":[{"season-type"...]}'''`

Comment: @quamrana: Ok, I see. How can I convert it into a valid JSON string?

Comment: Is not valid JSON, you cannot convert it unless you remove the quotes

Comment: Well, where did you get your string from? If you've typed it in as the question implies, you just typed it wrong.

Comment: It would be really ugly and pain for the eyes to replace "[ with [. The component which generates this string should take care to create a valid JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
import json

text = '''{"seasons":[{"season-type":"type1","start-day":10,"start-month":1,"end-day":31,"end-month":5},{"season-type":"type2","start-day":1,"start-month":9,"end-day":9,"end-month":1},{"season-type":"type3","start-day":1,"start-month":6,"end-day":30,"end-month":9}]}'''

obj = json.loads(text)
```

Your question has double quotes around the list:

```
text = '''{"seasons":"[{"season-type":  ...  ,"end-month":9}]"}'''
                     ^                                       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra quotes in the string. Try this one

```
{
 "seasons": [
    {"season-type":"type1","start-day":10,"start-month":1,"end-day":31,"end-month":5},
    {"season-type":"type2","start-day":1,"start-month":9,"end-day":9,"end-month":1},
    {"season-type":"type3","start-day":1,"start-month":6,"end-day":30,"end-month":9}]
}
```